# How to get the area of a small polygon with geography coordinates

Tags: javascript, geocoding

I'm doing a function to get the area of an irregular polygon on a map using GeoServer, i have the geographical coordinates, i search a lot of answers, like a transformation of the coordinates to cartesian (i guess that is the most easy) and also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection#Equal-area).
But are expensive to do and i don't have so much time to make it with projections.

Please help me to get the most approximate and simple area to make.

I started with [Gauss](https://www.mathopenref.com/coordpolygonarea2.html), after i tried with [this](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/7368f6157560c6d132de55f27e1147cd6a43c961/library/src/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.java#L222), but isn't the expected.

```
_showPerimeterAndArea(coordx, coordy) {
    const earthRadius = 6371;
    let area = 0;
    let size = coordx.length;
    let i = 0;
    if (size < 3) { return 0; }
    let prevTanLat = Math.tan(((Math.PI / 2) - toRadians(coordy[size-1])) / 2);
    let prevLng = toRadians(coordx[size-1]);
    /* For each edge, accumulate the signed area of the triangle formed by the North Pole
    and that edge ("polar triangle"). */
    for (i = 0; i < size-1; i++) {
        let tanLat = Math.tan((Math.PI / 2 - toRadians(coordx[i])) / 2 );
        let lng = toRadians(coordy[i]);
        area += this._polarTriangleArea(tanLat, lng, prevTanLat, prevLng);
        prevTanLat = tanLat;
        prevLng = lng;
    }
    return (area * earthRadius * earthRadius);
},
```

[example that doesn't shows the approximate area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXnB4.jpg)